# How force datanode and resourcemanager to use IP instead of hostname?

Tags: hadoop, docker-compose

I am running hadoop stack with composer, in the web ui, the services datanode and resourcemanager are showing with hostname instead of IP. Have a way to configure it to use IP?

[image]
[image]

My hadoop environments:

```
CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020

HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true

YARN_CONF_yarn_log___aggregation___enable=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_recovery_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_store_class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_fs_state___store_uri=/rmstate
YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_remote___app___log___dir=/app-logs
YARN_CONF_yarn_log_server_url=http://timelineserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_generic___application___history_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_system___metrics___publisher_enabled=true
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_address=resourcemanager:8032
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_webapp_address=resourcemanager:8088
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_address=resourcemanager:8030
YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_resource___tracker_address=resourcemanager:8031
```

Comment: Any specific reason to show ip address instead of showing host name?

Comment: Good question. I have managers on my network that need access using the web ui.

Comment: I'm pretty sure DNS is recommended over IPs for such deployments (Docker as well as Cloud infrastructure). Your datanodes could go down, the IP space is released, but the name of the container would be the same... That being said, using Docker at all, you don't have persistent data out of the box...

Comment: If you really needed an external way to access the web ui, then you can add an Nginx container, for example, with a reverse proxy, so you would have something like `http://nginx-ip:port/namenode` to go to one view, then maybe `/resourcemanager` for another

Comment: @cricket_007 that's a good idea. Thanks.